# Python: Given two list of file names find common ones based on date part

Tags: python

I have two data sources, each one has a list of files. The ask is to compare both lists and find out the files with same timestamp, and then output the result list based on an input parameter about which source I would like to see.

One complexity is that we can't do a straightforward file name comparison, as they are wrapped with strings about the source, we need to extract the date part first and compare that only, and then return the original file names.

Without a lot working knowledge with Python, I feel like what I've tried is not effective enough. For example, I was able to extract the date part from both sources and compare them with a chunk of code, but then not sure how to tight them back to the original file names.

```py
listA = ["apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190326-0.json", "apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190323-1.json", "apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190324-1.json"]
listB = ["apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190324-0.json", "apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190326-0.json"]

mySource = ['A', 'B']
allDates = {}
for s in mySource:
    fileList = []
    dateList = []

    if s == 'A':
        fileList = listA
    elif s == 'B':
        fileList = listB
    for f in fileList:
        date = f.rsplit('_',1)[-1].split('-')[0]
        if not date in dateList:
            dateList.append(date)

        if len(dateList) > 0:
            allDates[s] = dateList

        else:
            time.sleep(10)        
    if len(fileList) == 0:
        raise NoDataException

list(set(allDates['A']).intersection(allDates['B']))
```

This piece of code simply returns a list of common dates between files from both sources.

The output is:

```py
['20190326', '20190324'].
```

What I am looking for is

```py
listA = ["apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190326-0.json", "apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190324-1.json"] 
listB = ["apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190324-0.json", "apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190326-0.json"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build dicts for `listA` and `listB` that maps dates to file names, get the common keys (dates) using set intersection, and them map the dates back to file names for both `listA` and `listB`:

```
a, b = {}, {}
for l, d in (listA, a), (listB, b):
    for f in l:
        d.setdefault(f.rsplit('_', 1)[-1].split('-')[0], []).append(f)
common_keys = a.keys() & b.keys()
listA, listB = ([f for k in common_keys for f in d[k]] for d in (a, b))
```

so that given:

```
listA = ["apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190326-0.json", "apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190323-1.json", "apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190324-1.json"]
listB = ["apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190324-0.json", "apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190326-0.json", "apple://folderx/folderz/source_c_20190324-0.json"]
```

`listA` becomes:

```
['apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190324-1.json', 'apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190326-0.json']
```

`listB` becomes:

```
['apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190324-0.json', 'apple://folderx/folderz/source_c_20190324-0.json', 'apple://folderx/folderz/source_b_20190326-0.json']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It looks like a, b will only take the last file in the list with same date, in some cases 03/26 will have multiple files like ["apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190326-0.json", "apple://folderx/foldery/sourcea_20190326-1.json"], how can we make that work?

Comment: Follow up ask, it seems having a hard time when the common dates is only one day, the output becomes characters.

Comment: Ah, the problem with `operator.itemgetter` is that it returns a tuple when given multiple keys, but returns the value directly rather than a tuple of values when given only one key. I've fixed the code by iterating through the common keys instead of using `itemgetter`.